# Artificially slow down a vhost or php-fpm setup in Apache

Tags: performance, apache-http-server

Is there a good way to artificially slow down a Virtualhost (or PHP-FPM) in Apache 2.4?

By slow it down I mean "make it barely usable" - say 15 seconds to load a simple page.   Ideally I would like to be able to do this in the Virtualhost config, but if I can do it with options in PHP-FPM for that single VHOST that would work to.   For the sake of clarity I am running multiple sites - I only want specific ones handled.

I don't think that limiting the pm servers is going to provide an adequate level of slowdown.   I don't have easy access to change the DNS, so I want to avoid shaping traffic per IP address.  I would prefer not to mess with the contents of the vhost - ie I want to act at the server level.